# MYSQL - Syntax to create a procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure but it failed and I don't know why ?
The request:

```
delimiter //
drop  procedure if exists sp_edit_booking_owner;
create procedure sp_edit_booking_owner(v_pnr varchar(32), v_login varchar(200))

begin 
declare l_iduser int(11) default null; 

SELECT id_user INTO l_iduser FROM users WHERE userlogin = v_login;

if l_iduser is not null then                  

update book set iduser_c = l_iduser where bookingref = v_pnr;
update seg s join book b on s.id_book = b.id_book set s.id_user = l_iduser where b.bookingref = v_pnr;
update segmentown so join seg s on s.id_seg = so.id_seg join book b on s.id_book = b.id_book set so.id_user = l_iduser where b.bookingref = v_pnr;
update historyb hb join seg s on s.id_seg = hb.id_seg join book b on s.id_book = b.idbooking join users u on u.iduser = s.id_user_m set hb.eventowner = u.username where b.bookingref = v_pnr and  hb.event not like '%USER%';
update historyb hb join seg s on s.id_seg = hb.id_seg join book b on s.id_book = b.idbook join users u on u.id_user = s.id_user_m set hb.event = concat(u.username, '(USER)') where b.bookingpnr = v_pnr and  hb.event like '%USER%';

end if;

end;
//
delimiter ;
```

It is probably a synthax issue, but i can't tell from where...
Someone has an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your responses.
In fact it was nothing wrong in my first request.

You just have to execute this request via a terminal (mysql in command line).

Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

If you change the delimiter you need to use it until you change it again

```
delimiter //
drop  procedure if exists sp_edit_booking_owner //
create procedure sp_edit_booking_owner(v_pnr varchar(32), v_login varchar(200))
...
```

Fix that, I can create it on the MySQL I'm using

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

its works ;)

```
delimiter //
drop  procedure if exists sp_edit_booking_owner//
create procedure sp_edit_booking_owner(IN v_pnr varchar(32),IN v_login varchar(200))

begin 
declare l_iduser int(11) default null; 

SELECT id_user INTO l_iduser FROM users WHERE userlogin = v_login;

if l_iduser is not null then                  

update book set iduser_c = l_iduser where bookingref = v_pnr;
update seg s join book b on s.id_book = b.id_book set s.id_user = l_iduser where b.bookingref = v_pnr;
update segmentown so join seg s on s.id_seg = so.id_seg join book b on s.id_book = b.id_book set so.id_user = l_iduser where b.bookingref = v_pnr;
update historyb hb join seg s on s.id_seg = hb.id_seg join book b on s.id_book = b.idbooking join users u on u.iduser = s.id_user_m set hb.eventowner = u.username where b.bookingref = v_pnr and  hb.event not like '%USER%';
update historyb hb join seg s on s.id_seg = hb.id_seg join book b on s.id_book = b.idbook join users u on u.id_user = s.id_user_m set hb.event = concat(u.username, '(USER)') where b.bookingpnr = v_pnr and  hb.event like '%USER%';

end if;

end//

delimiter ;
```